# Spring mvc4 with Hibernate4 org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc 4 and hibernate 4 framework. tried out all the possible way that are provided on net but still not able to solve this.

I will list out my configuration files and autowired methods.

servlet-context.xml

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

 <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
  infrastructure -->

 <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
 <mvc:annotation-driven />

 <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
  up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample" />

 <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
 </bean>


 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
  destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
  <property name="username" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="chetan" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
    <value>com.sample.spring.pojo.User</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>
 <!-- <bean id="daoList" class="com.sample.spring.dao.UserDAOImpl" /> -->
<bean id = "transactionManager" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0">
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

```css
@Controller
public class HomeController {

 @Autowired
 private HomeServices userService;

 public HomeServices getUserService() {
  return userService;
 }

 public void setUserService(HomeServices userService) {
  this.userService = userService;
 }
  }
```

```css
@Service
public class HomeServices {

 @Autowired
 private UserDAO userDao;

 public UserDAO getUserDao() {
  return userDao;
 }

 public void setUserDao(UserDAO userDao) {
  this.userDao = userDao;
 }

 @Transactional
 //For methods
}
```

DAO interface

```css
public interface UserDAO {
methods here..
}
```

DAO implementation methods

```css
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

 @Autowired
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


 public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
  return sessionFactory;
 }

 public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
  this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
 }
    ....
  }
```

pom.xml

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>net.codejava</groupId>
 <artifactId>SpringMvcHibernateXML</artifactId>
 <name>SpringMvcHibernateXML</name>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <properties>
  <java-version>1.7</java-version>
  <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
  <java-version>1.6</java-version>
  <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
  <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
  <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <!-- Spring -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
   <exclusions>
    <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Hibernate -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Spring ORM -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- AspectJ -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
   <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Logging -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
   <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.15</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
     <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
     <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
     <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
     <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!-- @Inject -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Servlet -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Test -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.7</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

 </dependencies>
 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
     <additionalProjectnatures>
      <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
     </additionalProjectnatures>
     <additionalBuildcommands>
      <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
     </additionalBuildcommands>
     <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
     <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.6</source>
     <target>1.6</target>
     <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
     <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
     <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Exception simple says transaction not available for current thread, question is how your transaction is getting created/processed, what are your transactional boundaries, where exactly you are getting this error, controller layer, service layer or dao layer..???

Comment: At Dao lyer Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

Comment: try adding this in context file to scan for transaction in your code `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />`, let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried this too but not working